# The fastest way to initialize multiple constructors

Tags: php, oop, constructor

Lets assume that I have three class and each one  has its own constructor.
I want to initialize all of them  in one  class C so I don't make many object for each class,  should I use    `parent::__construct();`  in each class as the example! is there a better way to do it ?

```
class A {
     private  $a;
    public function __construct($a) {
        echo $this->a = $a;
    }
}
class B extends A {
    private  $b;
    public function __construct($a,$b) {
        echo $this->b = $b;
        parent::__construct($a);
    }
}

class C extends B {
private  $c;
    public function __construct($a,$b,$c) {
        echo $this->c = $c;
        parent::__construct($a,$b);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Don't be so lazy.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois that's what happens eventually .. it's the path of no return :D